# Minify a CSS file using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, regex, minify

The below code removes all newlines and spaces from a CSS file. But the problem is if the CSS file has something like this:

```
.sample {
    padding: 0px 2px 1px 4px;
}
```

Output will be :

```
.sample{padding:0px2px1px4px;}
```

I want that spaces in between  (0px 2px 1px 4px).

Here's the code that I have used :

```
$str=file_get_contents('sample.css');

//replace all new lines and spaces
$str = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);

//write the entire string
file_put_contents('sample.css', $str);
```

Comment: aren't there many scripts out there in the net that do that already? Why reinvent the wheel? Just picked the first google entry: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify

Comment: @Jeff : Sometimes the fist option isn't the best option. I tried Marrias Mullie's minify library as well as MrClay's library of the same name (https://github.com/mrclay/minify), and I prefer the latter. Also, the latter library is much more popular. Just compare the number of watchers, stars & forks of both libraries!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For minifying CSS in PHP, it's best to use [**Steve Clay**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779/steve-clay)'s [**Minify library**](https://github.com/mrclay/minify). There's no point in reinventing the wheel.

[**Here**](http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/19/minify-21-on-mrclayorg/)'s a brief walkthrough on how to install and configure the library.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways.

1. Using ready-made libraries such as **minify** and **CSSMin** .
2. Writing the method manually :

   ```
   function minify_css($css) {
    // Remove comments
    $css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $css);
    // Remove spaces before and after selectors, braces, and colons
    $css = preg_replace('/\s*([{}|:;,])\s+/', '$1', $css);
    // Remove remaining spaces and line breaks
    $css = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '',$css);

   return $css;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, adding the following line:

```
$str = preg_replace("/([0-9]*px(?!;))/", "$1 ", $str);
```

will add a space to any *px* string followed by something that is not a ;

This way you **fix** your code by adding spaces where you pointed out.

```
$str=file_get_contents('sample.css');

//replace all new lines and spaces
$str = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/([0-9]*px(?!;))/", "$1 ", $str);

//write the entire string
file_put_contents('sample.css', $str);
```

You could make use of any Php compression library like [minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) which offer complete css compression options.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The regex also removes valid spaces, e.g. from string values (e.g. `content: 'Click Here!'`) or any non-px units (e.g. `padding: 2% 5vh 3em 7mm;`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the tabs and spaces around each line, but keep the spaces inside the styles. You should just `explode()` the whole content with `\n` as the token delimiter and iterate over each line and use php's trim() on it, then `implode()` it without any delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple yet effective solution:

```
// Get style contents    
$style = file_put_contents('your_style.css');

// Minify it
$minified = $style;
$minified = str_replace("\n", "", $minified);
$minified = str_replace("  ", " ", $minified);
$minified = str_replace("  ", " ", $minified);
$minified = str_replace(" {", "{", $minified);
$minified = str_replace("{ ", "{", $minified);
$minified = str_replace(" }", "}", $minified);
$minified = str_replace("} ", "}", $minified);
$minified = str_replace(", ", ",", $minified);
$minified = str_replace("; ", ";", $minified);
$minified = str_replace(": ", ":", $minified);

// Write it
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
echo $minified;
```

It will remove all empty spaces that are not necessary. It won't however remove comments or replace 4 numbers to 1 where it could be replaced, but it does great job however.
Let me know if I am missing something or if you have any ideas how comment removal and/or other functions could be easily added to it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this small `preg_replace`:

```
$css = preg_replace(
  array('/\s*(\w)\s*{\s*/','/\s*(\S*:)(\s*)([^;]*)(\s|\n)*;(\n|\s)*/','/\n/','/\s*}\s*/'), 
  array('$1{ ','$1$3;',"",'} '),
  $css
);
```

It collapses everything appropriately - leaving spaces within the property definition, but does not remove comments.

Comment: Doesn't work for @import url. The regex removes the space between `import` and `url`. Works well otherwise.